What is OpenVMS command for Linux du --summarize --human-readable
RSX-11M command:
PIP /FREE

displays the free space on the disks.
On Linux there is:
du --summarize --human-readable

What OpenVMS DCL command for this?

$ show quota
Show the number of blocks authorized for the current user.

$ show device disk$v922
Device                  Device           Error   Volume          Free  Trans Mnt
 Name                   Status           Count    Label         Blocks Count Cnt
V922$DKA0:              Mounted              0    V922          6023072  180   1

